# How to Validate a MD5 Hash Being Posted From a Python Script in Laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, md5, php-carbon

Ok , so I have a python script that will register a new user in Laravel if the provided login fails. In the python script I am passing the following:

```
import hashlib 
import strftime

hashedMessage = hashlib.md5()
hashedMessage.update("Password"+strftime("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M"))
```

This will create a hashed message as such:

> Password+07/12/2018-3:01

So now in Laravel, I need to be able to verify that this hash is valid before allowing the script to register a new user.

I'm kinda new to the built in validator in Laravel and unsure of how to generate that hashed message within. I know as far as the date and time part of it, I can use something such as Carbon. But I am unsure of how to generate the hashed message in Laravel and be able to compare it to the one being sent by the script.

I see that Laravel has better support for bcrypt but it seems to make it way more complicated for the simple task that I am trying to accomplish. Please let me know if this is not the case.

If you have any questions them let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For md5 you can do something as simple as:

```
if (request()->input('hashed_message') === md5('Password+' . now()->format('m/d/Y-H:m'))) {
   // match
}
```

This will fail, however, if the request is sent at the minute boundary - i.e. sent at 3:01:59 but received at 3:02:00.